# Iterator integer for DataBind and/or asp:Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a LINQ query that returns a custom object. The object is derived from a `Dictionary<T>` of result objects, each with a URL. My LINQ object groups the `Dictionary<T>` according to a URL property in T, and then takes the `object.First()` item from the Group of URLs.

Now I have a LINQ object all with unique URLs, and a count too of how many times the URL was repeated in the original `Dictionary<T>.`

Ok, at this point I perform a DataBind on my LINQ object, to an ASP page. The DataBind is to an `<asp:Repeater>` with an `ItemTemplate`.

What I want is to get the iterator of the `<asp:Repeater>` as if it is a simple `for (int i = 0; ... i++)` type loop. This is so I can dynamically display the number of the result (say if there was a list of five results, each result would have 1. Result .... 2. Result .... 3. Result ...

I do not know how many result will be there to start with (there could be none).

How could this be achieved? Could I use a lambda expression to alter the results object and hold an integer for its position in my Linq list??

I hope this isn't too confusing! Please ask if you need a better explanation. Much appreciated, as always.

Comment: What exactly can you not achieve? Does the binding fail?

Comment: As simple as using an html numbered list you mean?

Comment: The binding is fine. Can't use HTML because I don't know how many results there will be (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the row number in `Repeater` it is actually a lot easier than I think you realize.  You don't need to know the current index since you can count / increment a value everytime a bind occurs and display it.

First create a integer in your .cs code. Eg:

```
public partial class _YourPageName : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int _itemCounter = 0;
```

Then in your `Repeater` `ItemTemplate` you just need to display it using a `Literal` or something.

```
<asp:Literal ID="litCount" runat="server" OnDataBinding="litCount_DataBinding" />
```

Then implement it the `DataBinding` event for the `Literal` or whatever you want to use:

```
protected void litCount_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _itemCounter++;
    Literal lt = (Literal)(sender);
    lt.Text = _itemCounter.ToString();
}
```

Each time the `ItemTemplate` is bound it will increment the counter and display it.

Maybe I am over simplifying your issue though.

Comment: Not over simplifying... I think I was over complicating! This could be the winner for my website, will let you know when I implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *entirely* clear what you're doing, particularly as you've referred to `Dictionary` as if it had one type parameter instead of two, but you might want to consider this:

```
var items = originalItems.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index });
```

That overload of `Select` provides the index for each entry as it iterators - and I've just captured the results in an anonymous type. (You might want to use a `Tuple<,>` instead if you're using .NET 4; it depends on where the results will be used.)

This will start at Index=0 of course - to start from 1 you'd need:

```
var items = originalItems.Select((Value, idx) => new { Value, Index = idx + 1 });
```

(Parameter renamed to keep it on one short line for Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Very good point regarding the Dictionary! You've answered four of my questions on SO for this project (so far)! Could almost claim to be collaborating! :)